# How to create a 3D object that keeps rotating?

Tags: matlab, 3d

I have used `isosurface` function as follows:

```
isosurface(data);
grid on; axis equal;
colormap copper;
alpha(0.1);
hold on;
```

How do I make the object rotate on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking about two possible solutions:

First, you could redraw the surface a number of times, each time incrementing by a small angle the position. Something like:

```
for i=1:length_of_animation
    [theta,phi,r] = cart2sph(x,y,z);
    [x,y,z] = sph2cart(theta+small_angle, phi, r);
    delete(h);
    h = isosurface(x,y,z)
end
```

Second, you could move the camera around the plot using the `campos` function. see [mathworks details](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/campos.html). This will not make the surface rotate, but will make the view point rotate. Playing with the camera could be a little tricky tho.